# Phonegap JQTouch Multiple Page Form - stored info till final POST

Tags: html, jqtouch, cordova

What's the easiest way to implement a multi-page form and save the information until the final POST using JQTouch for the Phonegap framework?

Basically, I want to create a multiple page form with JQTouch and at the end POST/send all information entered to a PHP page on my server, but am having trouble figuring out the best way to save the users info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Collect all of the variables from their inputs and then use Ajax to post them to the web.